# Resposive background doesn't fill screen in mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am doing a simple site currently and I have a cover background that looks great on desktop but when I switch to mobile, the background only fills half the screen?

Here is my code.

```
.bg {
 background: url('/imgs/storm.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

and here is the address of the page.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djqma8ce/

Answer (score 0):

How are you going about your mobile testing? Using the device mode in chrome developer tools it looks like it is working fine.